# Plug USB 3.1 Gen 2 to non-USB-C motherboard

Tags: usb-3.1-type-c

I've built a "gaming" computer, good perfs, but I did a small mistake : my case (Fractal design R6) have a USB-C port in front panel, but my motherboard (MSI Z370 Gaming Plus), don't have a USB 3.1 Gen 2 port ...

How can I plug him ? Is there any convertor ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are adapters to achieve what you want, but they are not simple, and definitely not cheap: https://www.moddiy.com/products/Motherboard-USB-3.0-Header-to-New-USB-3.1-Front-Panel-Header-Converter.html

Maybe even a separate usb3.1 gen2 pci express controller is a better bet (arround the same price, and likely faster), as stated on other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! BTW, the adapter is perfectly what I was looking for, and for the moment, the only PCIe card with header expansion slot i've found is more expensive :/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to purchase a USB 3.1 Gen 2 PCIe card with a header expansion slot.  Make sure it comes with a cable that is long enough to reach the connector on the case.

Here are some [examples](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_18?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=usb%203.1%20gen%202%20pcie%20card&sprefix=usb%203.1%20gen%202%20pcie%2Caps%2C147&crid=9F9QIILPZ0QW&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ausb%203.1%20gen%202%20pcie%20card).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I found this one (https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-USB-PCIE-Card-USB/dp/B01I39D15A) but really not cheap ^^' Do you know cheaper cards ?

Comment: @HeavyNounours Unfortunately, I do not.  Its not something I follow.  If this answer was helpful vote it up.  If it was the solution, please accept it.  This allows people who are searching for the same problem as you to find possible solutions.  :D